# What is "ensure that sleepable APIs are not used"

Tags: linux, gpio

**Background:**

I am going to ask basic questions as I am not sure I understand the matters, and I am searching in the dark territory.

I am developing GPIO bitbanging in user space through GPIO V2 API. It works relatively quickly, but I want it to run quicker. Looking into the `gpiod` interface I understand that I have designed something very similar, but in user space.

I am investigating if I need to design device driver using GPIOs configured as IRQs. It is not clear for me how to do it - I will need new class for the device as any standard class like spi, i2c etc do not fit.

The biggest problem with mu user space code is waiting for the specific pin state. First attempt was using epoll, and the delays were huge. Now I have balanced way for waiting - epoll for waits with unknown readiness time, and active polling for predictable events. It appeared that active polling is much-much faster than epolling.

Therefore the current pain point for me is this epolling/polling, as all other calls are performed using `ioctl` wchich seem to go directly into the gpiod/GPIO subsystem in the kernel.

**Question:**

reading [this document](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/driver-api/gpio/driver.rst) I see that drivers have the same non-real-time-nature problem:

> ensure that sleepable APIs are not used as part irq_chip implementation If sleepable APIs have to be used, these can be done from the .irq_bus_lock() and .irq_bus_unlock() callbacks

I looked through the web and did not find readily available description of "sleepable API". This might be easy and self-describing, and I suspect epoll/usleep are the ones meant.

The problem I get is what APIs should be used if "sleepable" are not advised? Active polling as I do right now in user space? But this will eat CPU time, and what is the point then going to kernel level from user space?

**Update:** the platform I am running application on is 4-core ARM. Explicitly forced scheduler the process/thread onto one of the cores, performance has soared, even in the user space.

Comment: So this is kernel documentation when you want to add a new gpio driver fir example for your custom device. I think you wang to use gpio, consider using libgpiod , https://github.com/brgl/libgpiod

Comment: This is what I designed. I also use ioctls. libgpiod is not driver or kernel module, it seems to be running in user space.

Comment: You are mixing two things: 1) user space APIs, and 2) Linux kernel atomicity (non-sleepable context). The comment is related to IRQ chips that are connected to the buses which might require sleeping (e.g., I²C). For that you need to implement the respective locking mechanisms (see, for example, _drivers/gpio/gpio-pca953x.c_ in the Linux kernel source tree). In any case, according to your problem I may say "yes, you need a brand new bitbanging driver in the kernel space". And there are plenty of the examples in the Linux kernel source tree. You may check _spi-gpio.c) and take ideas from there.

Comment: `I get is what APIs should be used if "sleepable" are not advised? Active polling as I do right now in user space?` Again, you are reading _kernel_ function implementation. There is no "poll" in kernel. There is msleep_interruptible. You should not use any sleepable API in IRQ context, because it is handling IRQ and cpu is blocked. By "sleepable", I would understand any operation that can wait. Other way it's called is "atomic" functions - i.e. function that execute instantly, and only they should be used in IRQ handling. See https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/ in particular chapter 10.

Comment: `and I suspect epoll/usleep are the ones meant.` No, epoll and usleep are _user_ space functions, they are irrelevant to kernel space. All they do is execute a syscall. Any function that calls for example `wait_event_interruptible` would be a sleepable function, any function that "waits" for anything has to "sleep". `what is the point then going to kernel level from user space?` The second rule of optimization is profile before optimizing.

Comment: @KamilCuk do I understand properly that kernel driver/module is not executed at all while it is waiting for related interrupt? Then, when interrupt arrives, callback in the kernel is invoked, and driver/module can access the related device requiring attention. But what user application is doing between the time when it realized it needs response from driver (and driver sets irq line active) and it receiving the notification of the interrupt? Is it doing poll? What is the latency of the poll implementation in the user space, and where is the guarantee bottleneck will not be the user space poll?

Comment: The kernel interrupt handler is only called when an interrupt occurs.  A poll() blocks the userspace process until the event is available, so the userspace process will be doing nothing.  i.e. waiting for an event uses no CPU resource.  Writing drivers in userspace is [explicitly frowned upon](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/gpio/using-gpio.html) - write a kernel driver instead.  Userspace drivers will always suffer from latency due to kernel/userspace context switching that in-kernel drivers avoid.

Comment: @KentGibson thanks. Is there a guarantee, and within which time it is guaranteed, that poll() will be unblocked/execution will be returned to in the userspace as soon as driver makes file handle ready? This seems to be a primary question now. My experiments show that if I actively poll GPIO the whole thing performs much better than when I use poll() which may have delays up to hundreds of milliseconds to be awaken. So what is the point of making things super fast in kernel and then sit for 100 ms in the poll() in the user space until it is turned to for processing that driver was rushing for?

Comment: When using interrupts, there is always the interrupt latency to deal with, and that depends on your platform.  Tight polling is always faster, but wasteful of CPU.  The interrupt will queue the event and immediately wake the userspace process, which will then get run when the scheduler sees fit. There is no guarantee - it depends on the scheduler.  I can't comment on what your experiments show without more information, and this probably isn't the best forum. A 100ms delay from the poll() is not consistent with what I've seen, e.g. ~60usec on a Pi4.

Comment: The kernel timestamps the events in the interrupt handler to provide the best possible estimate of when the interrupt occurred and, to reduce the chance of lost interrupts, queues them for subsequent processing by userspace.  If you need the fastest possible response to that interrupt then in-kernel is always going to be faster.  Linux is not an RTOS so there are no guarantees, either in userspace or in-kernel.